# How to implement "Transaction Controller" in locust

Tags: python, performance, jmeter, locust, throughput

Is there a way to make Locust measure (completed tasks/second) assuming we have more that one request in the task, as the Jmeter dose by using "Transaction Controller"

measuring performance by how many completed flows (several requests) per second

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would reduce your work down to a single request or action per task. You can use [SequentialTasks](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#sequentialtaskset-class) or put [TaskSets inside TaskSets](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/tasksets.html) to structure the work however you need it to be, then Locust will do all the work for you.

Alternatively, you can create your own [User](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#user-class) class with your code however you want and use [EventHooks](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#event-hooks) to manually tell Locust when stuff happens by firing a [request](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#locust.event.Events.request) event. You can call it with `request_type` as whatever label you want for tasks to be tagged with as a type and `name` to be whatever you want the task to be called when it reports.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @solowalkers answer you may want to check out locust-plugins TransactionManager.

See the transaction_example* files here https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/tree/master/examples

Comment: So assuming that i have the following flow:
1. login 
2. add user
3. logout 
and i want to know how many flows/s the server can handle using the TransactionManager will not give this specific number as the jmeter "Transaction Controller" right ?